# Modulus of Continuity and Fourier Series

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a $2\pi$-periodic function and define $\Omega(f,h)=|f(x+h)-f(x)|_{L^1}$. Show that exists a constant $C>0$ with $|\hat f(n)|\leq C.\Omega(f,h)$, where $|\hat f(n)|$ are the complex coefficient.

If I can show this, then is direct that if $f$ is Holder, then $|\hat f(n)|\leq M n^{ -\alpha}$, which is my main problem. But, I am failing to relate $|\hat f(n)|$ with $|f(x+h)-f(x)|_{L^1}$

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: use a change of variable to prove that $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(f(t + \frac{\pi}{n}) - f(t)\right)e^{int}dt$

Comment: Thanks @ChrisJanjigian, I will try!

Comment: Fair warning, I probably have negative signs wrong all over that formula but something to that effect is true.

Comment: I get it, we made a change of variable, get an equality $\hat{f}=a=b$ and then, take $\hat{f}=(a+b)/2$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered by [Chris Janjigian](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/597578/modulus-of-continuity-and-fourier-series#comment1259159_597578) in a comment. Substitution $t=s+\pi/n$ in 
$$\hat{f}(n) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}  f(t) e^{-int}\,dt$$
yields, in view of periodicity,
$$\hat{f}(n) =\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}  f(s + \pi/n)  e^{-ins-i\pi}\,ds
=- \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}  f(s + \pi/n)  e^{-ins }\,ds$$
The average of two integrals is again $\hat{f}(n)$:
$$ \hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} \left(f(t + \pi/n) - f(t)\right)e^{int}\,dt$$
Hence $ |\hat{f}(n)|\le \frac1{4\pi}\Omega(f,\pi/n)$.